# Performance / Alternatives - removing x elements from start of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance

I have an object with multiple arrays, for example:

```
var data = {
  ids: [],
  names: [],
  ages: [],
  relations: [],
}
```

I keep these arrays trimmed to the minimum amount of data I need (250 elements), while new data is being added continuously as new data becomes available. This means the other functions have significantly smaller arrays to deal with (250 elements vs 70k), and has improved logic that might take 20 seconds to complete, to complete in ±2 seconds.

I made a simple function to loop through the arrays in my object, and trim each with `array.slice` to the desired length provided as a parameter:

```
  trimPropertiesInObject(object, targetLength){
    for (var prop in object){
      var array = object[prop];

      object[prop] = array.slice(array.length-targetLength, array.length);
    }
    return object;
  }
  trimPropertiesInObject(data, 250);
```

This works very well, is relatively fast and keeps my arrays within my object trimmed to exactly 250 elements, though I've noticed it's still a bottleneck in the overall execution happening as fast as the CPU core allows (500+ times per second, in this example).

Since this still shows as a bottleneck in the 0x flamegraph, I was curious if there's further room for optimization, as that would technically allow more iterations per second.

I saw a ton of benchmark threads, though most seem to be for cloning arrays or removing elements at the end. I need to explicitly remove x elements from the start of the array, to trim the array to the exact length of y.

Any thoughts on further optimizing such a simple function? Is there a faster alternative to `array.slice` in this scenario? Or should I be looking to do the for loop differently?

Comment: Have you considered using a circular buffer instead which could have an underlying linked list or array it uses to manage the data? This is the data structure used commonly for this use case (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Comment: Thank you @megawac, the concept is new to me and I'll certainly read into it! Why reinvent the wheel!

Comment: If all elements are going to remain in memory anyway (on the main largest arrays), @megawac's suggestion would be in fact an answer (it should have been written as an official answer).

In general, you could create a view of the array, by wrapping it into a new custom class that looks and feel like an array-ish object (but makes no physical changes to anything, it would only handle soft-references to the index ranges you care about)

Comment: If you're just trimming elements from the front, you might consider using `.splice` instead. The `.slice` method will create a shallow copy of the array whereas `.splice` will modify it in place (which will be faster). So changing the `slice` line to be `array.splice(0, array.length - targetLength)` might give a performance boost.

Comment: Thanks @CRice that was an easy one to test right away! That gave a minor improvement across several tests, which is great! Will try the circular buffer suggestions too.